# Validar un Objeto dentro de set, list, map

Tags: c++, poo, algoritmos, c++11, c++98

```
class Coordenada(){
    int fila;
    int columna;
    //los getter and setter
}

int main(){
   std::set<Coordena> coordenadaSet(Coordenada(4,6));
   Coordenada coordenada(5,6);
   if(coordendaSet.find(coordenada) != coordenadaSet.end()){
        cout << "encontro";
   } else{
        cout << "fallaste";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

La cuestión de este ejemplo es saber como puedo comparar objetos, ya intente hacerlo con sobrecarga de operador a la coordenada "operator== o operator!=" alguna sabe como hacerlo. Gracias.

Answer (score 5):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set

```
template<
  class Key,
  class Compare = std::less<Key>,
  class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class set;
```

> Sorting is done using the key comparison function Compare. Search, removal, and insertion operations have logarithmic complexity

Es decir, la implementación de `set` no usa `==` ni `!=` (lo cual es lógico porque si las operaciones tienen complejidad logarítmica es que internamente los datos están ordenados, y `==` o `!=` no sirven para ordenar).

Para definir `Compare`, puedes crear un *functor*, un *struct*  que define el operador `()`.

```
struct ComparadorCoordenada {
  bool operator() (const Coordenada& izq, const Coordenada& der) const {
    if (izq.fila < der.fila) {
      return true;
    }
    if (izq.fila > der.fila) {
      return false;
    }
    return izq.columna < der.columna;
  }
};

set<Coordenada, ComparadorCoordenada> miSet;
```

#### Actualización

Viendo que `Compare` tenía un valor por defecto `std::less`, me ha picado la curiosidad y he revisado [la documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less), que me dice:

> Unless specialized, invokes operator< on type T.

Es decir, basta con sobrecargar el operador `<` para que el `set` funcione, sin necesidad de un functor.

Moraleja: Leer siempre la documentación.

Comment: Para programar la comparación es más fácil y limpio usar [`std::tie`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dgUq9g1TbC2hPuXu): `bool operator <(const Coordenada &a, const Coordenada &b){ return std::tie(a.x, a.y) < std::tie(b.x, b.y); }`

Answer (score 3):

Ya ibas por buen camino, la función `find` te puede ayudar; pero si quieres generalizar la búsqueda para cualquier contenedor (set, list o map) deberías valorar usar funciones genéricas como [`std::find` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
template <typename contenedor_t, typename valor_t>
bool contenedor_contiene(const contenedor_t &contenedor, const valor_t &valor)
{
    return std::find(std::begin(contenedor), std::end(contenedor), valor) != std::end(contenedor);
}
```

Puedes usar el código anterior con cualquier contenedor no asociativo:

```
std::set<Coordenada>       s{{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}, {7,8}, {9,0}};
std::list<Coordenada>      l{{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}, {7,8}, {9,0}};
std::vector<Coordenada>    v{{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}, {7,8}, {9,0}};
std::array<Coordenada, 5>  a{{{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}, {7,8}, {9,0}}};
Coordenada                 c[]{{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}, {7,8}, {9,0}};

std::cout << contenedor_contiene(s, Coordenada{0,9}); // Falso
std::cout << contenedor_contiene(s, Coordenada{9,0}); // Verdadero
std::cout << contenedor_contiene(l, Coordenada{0,9}); // Falso
std::cout << contenedor_contiene(l, Coordenada{9,0}); // Verdadero
std::cout << contenedor_contiene(v, Coordenada{0,9}); // Falso
std::cout << contenedor_contiene(v, Coordenada{9,0}); // Verdadero
std::cout << contenedor_contiene(a, Coordenada{0,9}); // Falso
std::cout << contenedor_contiene(a, Coordenada{9,0}); // Verdadero
std::cout << contenedor_contiene(c, Coordenada{0,9}); // Falso
std::cout << contenedor_contiene(c, Coordenada{9,0}); // Verdadero
```

Para contenedores asociativos debes especificar dónde buscar el valor, yo asumo que es en el valor (no en la clave):

```
template <typename contenedor_asociativo_t, typename valor_t>
bool contiene_en_valor(const contenedor_asociativo_t &contenedor, const valor_t &valor)
{
    return std::find_if(std::begin(contenedor), std::end(contenedor),
                        [&](auto &kv) { return kv.second == valor; }) != std::end(contenedor);
}
```

Puedes usar el código anterior con contenedores asociativos:

```
std::map<int, Coordenada> m;
m.insert({0, {1,2}});
m.insert({0, {3,4}});
std::cout << contiene_en_valor(m, Coordenada{4,3}); // Falso
std::cout << contiene_en_valor(m, Coordenada{3,4}); // Verdadero
```

Los ejemplos asumen que `Coordenada` dispone de un operador de equidad (`==`).